# why my code print 'download over' first, and then start to download html pages?

Tags: node.js, promise

```
function downloadAsync(url, name) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function(err, response, body) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'downloaded_html', name), body);
        console.log('got ' + url);
        resolve();
      }
    })
  })
}

var urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']

var promises = urls.map(function(url, i) {
  var name = i + '.html'
  downloadAsync(url, name)
})

Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
  console.log('download over')
})
```

why my code print 'download over' first, and then start to download html pages?
this code supposed to download html pages first and then print 'download over'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return in your map

```
return downloadAsync(url, name);
```

Basically our code isn't waiting for the promises to resolve because there are no promises in your promises array.